# In table flex-around flexbox property doesn't work on a tr?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use order property on a table, thus I try to make a table using `flexbox` but I can't make the column spread equally, I'm stuck at `tr` part.

```
table tr {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}
table th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/645udp3r/

Comment: Probably going to be tricky, since table layouts are often fixed and are not flexible as you think.

Comment: @Terry it doesn't have to be responsive, it's hard to make a normal table with flexbox? I just want to use the order property.

Comment: Unfortunately it often is, because the parent has `display: table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the `display` property of `table` and `thead` too. Also `flex:1` to the `th` so that it can spread equally

```css
table,
thead {
  display: block
}

table tr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

table th:last-child {
  order: 1;
}
table th:first-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        name
      </th>
      <th>
        age
      </th>
      <th>
        school
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: didn't know it is this easy, forgot to remove the default display table.